# Proving that a positive operator has a unique square root

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Rudin's functional analysis page 331 theorem 12.33) proves this. He proves uniqueness by 'going back' to the general algebra setting. I was just wondering whether there is a more direct way of doing this using the spectral decomposition of $T$ and the associated functional calculus.

Comment: There's an even simpler way, just using power series! Check out Reed-Simon's Functional Analysis Volume 1 Theorem VI.9 (p 196).

Comment: I think you mean a unique positive square root

Comment: Actually the methods of Rudin and that of Reed-Simon are basically the same (the closed algebra generated by $T$ contains $p(T)$ for all polynomials $p(x)$ and their limits), but Reed and Simon use an explicit approximation of the square root function in terms of a polynomial. Then it depends on whether you think a power series analysis is simpler than Stone-Weierstrass (IMO it is not).